# Display maximum value and items for knapsack python recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

We need to return the maximum value of items, along with the items that make up that maximum value.

The list input is in the format of `[[weight1, value1], [weight2, value2]]`.

With the following code, I return only the maximum value.

Could someone please help me return that value along with the items please?

```
def knapsack(capacity, itemList):
    """
    Returns the maximum value and the list of items to keep.
    """
    if len(itemList) == 0:
        return 0
    elif itemList[-1][0] > capacity:
        return knapsack(capacity, itemList[:-1])
    else:
        return max(
            knapsack(capacity, itemList[:-1]),
            knapsack(capacity-itemList[-1][0], itemList[:-1]) + itemList[-1][1])

print (knapsack(6, [[1, 4], [5, 150], [4, 180]]))
# should return [184, [[1, 4], [4, 180]]]
# returns 184
```

Comment: Add another parameter to the fnc: `knapsack(capacity, itemList, result_items=[])`. Add to items accordingly in your fnc and pass the list on to the recursive calls.

Comment: @schwobaseggl **do not use `[]`** this is a mutable type and will retain values if the function is called again. Instead, you can use `result_items=None` and instantiate a new list if it is.

Comment: @o_o True, thx for attention!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by storing the solutions to recursive subcalls along the way.  Your solution basically says the solution to the knapsack problem with N items and capacity C is the max of:

```
Soln(N,C)  = max ( Soln(N-1,C), Soln(N-1, C-W_n) + Vc)
```

So if we store the solutions to these subproblems in dict (an array could also be used), you can work backwards using the same logic.  See if the solution to the N,C problem is equal to the N-1, C problem.  If so, item N is not in the sack, otherwise it is.

```
d = {} #maps from (itemCount, capacity) to best Value 
# (also useful for when/if you convert to dp/memoized version)
def knapsack(capacity, itemList):
    """
    Returns the maximum value and the list of items to keep.
    """
    if len(itemList) == 0:
        return 0 
    elif itemList[-1][0] > capacity:
        ans = knapsack(capacity, itemList[:-1])
        d[(len(itemList), capacity)] = ans
        return ans 
    else:
        ans = max(knapsack(capacity, itemList[:-1]), knapsack(capacity-itemList[-1][0], itemList[:-1]) + itemList[-1][1])
        d[(len(itemList), capacity)] = ans
        return ans

items = [[5, 150], [1, 4], [4, 180]]
startCap = 6
print knapsack(startCap, items)


#Work Backwards
itemNo = 3
startCap = 6
curValue = d[(itemNo,startCap)]
myList = []

while itemNo > 0:
    if (itemNo == 1 or curValue != d[(itemNo-1, startCap)]) and items[itemNo-1][0] < startCap: #item was included
        myList = [itemNo] + myList
        startCap -= items[itemNo-1][0] #subtract the capacity 
        curValue -= items[itemNo-1][1]
    itemNo -= 1
print myList #outputs [2,3]
```

Answer (score -3):

I think a tuple would actually make a bit more sense since you presumably would not modify the value. You can first note that there is actually no need to return the value if you already have the items, because you can sum them afterwards. One way to do this is with an extra parameter.
I'll only give you the base cases :)

```
def knapsack(capacity, itemList, taken):
    """
    Returns the maximum value and the list of items to keep.
    """
    if len(itemList) == 0:
        return (0,taken)
    elif itemList[-1][0] > capacity:
        return (knapsack(capacity, itemList[:-1]), taken)
    else:
        #you will need to compute the values first, save them, and then update the taken variable as needed depending on the max
        return max(
            knapsack(capacity, itemList[:-1]),
            knapsack(capacity-itemList[-1][0], itemList[:-1]) + itemList[-1][1])

print (knapsack(6, [[1, 4], [5, 150], [4, 180]]))
# should return [184, [[1, 4], [4, 180]]]
# returns 184
```

Comment: I think you meant to "take" itemList[-1] in the last line of the function.

Comment: I think this currently will throw an error, as the knapsack func now requires 3 args and is called in a few places with only 2

Comment: I did not update the recursive case, but only the base cases :)